# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar la versión de Gradle en Ionic?

Tags: ionic, ionic3, ionic2, ionic-framework

Siempre que abro un proyecto compilado de Ionic en Android me dice que la versión instalada no es la recomendada, si le doy a Update me deja de funcionar la aplicación. He desinstalado y vuelto a instalar ionic y me sigue pasando ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.6.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.3, (and 7 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.13.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.5.0
   OS     : macOS Mojave
   Xcode  : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

[image: Actualización recomendada de Gradle]